# HTMX AJAX dependency (vs Fetch API)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, fetch-api, htmx

HTMX interests me because I my abilities and interests primarily lie on the backend side of the house, but I'd still like my web applications to feel interactive.

From what I've read, AJAX is slowly being phased out in favor of the JS standard, Fetch API. HTMX was originally released in 2020, so I'm curious why the developers used AJAX at all.

My questions are:

1. For HTMX longevity, will the package eventually need to swap AJAX for Fetch?
2. Are there elements of Ajax that go beyond what Fetch was intended for?

Sources

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/AJAX
2. https://htmx.org/docs/#ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I've read, AJAX is slowly being phased out in favor of the JS standard, Fetch API.

No.

That's like saying "Driving is slowly being phased out in favor of cars".

`fetch` is an API for performing Ajax.

You might be confusing Ajax for `XMLHttpRequest`.

> For HTMX longevity, will the package eventually need to swap AJAX for Fetch?

Browser vendors care a great deal about backwards compatibility. Support for the APIs that HTMX depends on is highly unlikely to go away.

> Are there elements of Ajax that go beyond what Fetch was intended for?

No.

Answer (score 0):

HTMX claim compatibility to IE11.

IE11 is not compatible with Fetch Api
https://caniuse.com/?search=%20Fetch%20API

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question is about compatibility with future browsers (it is concerned that browsers will stop supporting XHR which HTMX appears to depend on), not past ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there elements of Ajax that go beyond what Fetch was intended for?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)#Fetch_example mentions 2 differences between `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest`, but doesn't seem to highlight any drawbacks:

1. fetch() won't reject on HTTP error status
2. fetch() won't send cross-origin cookies

As I saw in the htmx source code, it's using the abort and timeout capabilities of `XMLHttpRequest`.

`fetch` would need a few lines of extra code deal with those features, so over all, the `fetch` code might end up being just as complex as the current `XMLHttpRequest` implementation.